# Change the color of UIImage extracted from a PDF in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, image-processing, uiimage

I have a PDF file, I need to extract each page from the PDF as a `UIImage` and then change the colour of the `UIImage` based on the user settings and load this to a `UICollectionViewCell`. I had some how managed to do this and to avoid the jerky scroll I am preloading some images and releasing them as the pages are passed. But it takes a considerable amount of memory which comes down once the images are rendered and also considerable amount of time for rendering. Please have a look at the piece of code I had done

```
-(UIImage *)getImageFromPDF:(int)pg withColor:(int)color{
    // create PDF document

    CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath]);

    // get the first page
    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, pg);


    // create a bitmap context
    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    CGFloat pdfScale = 1.0f;//self.view.frame.size.width/pageRect.size.width;
    pageRect.size = CGSizeMake(pageRect.size.width * pdfScale, pageRect.size.height * pdfScale);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(pageRect.size, YES, pdfScale);

    // flip the context
    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, pageRect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1, -1);

    // draw the page into the bitmap context
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), page);
    CGPDFDocumentRelease(document);

    // get the image from the context
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if(color==1)
        return image;
    else
    {
        CGRect contextRect;
        contextRect.origin.x = 0.0f;
        contextRect.origin.y = 0.0f;
        contextRect.size = [image size];
        // Retrieve source image and begin image context
        CGSize itemImageSize = [image size];
        CGPoint itemImagePosition;
        itemImagePosition.x = ceilf((contextRect.size.width - itemImageSize.width) / 2);
        itemImagePosition.y = ceilf((contextRect.size.height - itemImageSize.height) );

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextRect.size);

        CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        // Setup shadow
        // Setup transparency layer and clip to mask
        //CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(c, NULL);
        CGContextScaleCTM(c, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextClipToMask(c, CGRectMake(itemImagePosition.x, -itemImagePosition.y, itemImageSize.width, -itemImageSize.height), [image CGImage]);

        switch (color) {
            case 1:
                CGContextSetRGBFillColor(c, 1, 1, 1, 1);
                break;

            case 2:
                CGContextSetRGBFillColor(c, 0, 0, 0, 1);
                break;

            case 3:
                CGContextSetRGBFillColor(c, 0.95686, 0.929412, 0.85098, 1);
                break;

            default:
                CGContextSetRGBFillColor(c, 1, 1, 1, 1);
                break;
        }

        contextRect.size.height = -contextRect.size.height;
        contextRect.size.height -= 15;
        // Fill and end the transparency layer
        CGContextFillRect(c, contextRect);

        UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return img;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to reduce the memory usage and rendering time, so that the user can scroll smoothly through the pages. I am passing the page number and the colour option to the function

`-(UIImage *)getImageFromPDF:(int)pg withColor:(int)color`

The colour option 1 is the default colour of the image extracted from the PDF so the colouring section is skipped and the `UIImage` is returned straight away.
This is working but takes considerable amount of time. Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating  `CGPDFDocumentRef document`  and `CGContextRef` for each pass of function, create them once, using either static or private properties. Because creating them will be lot of memory overhead, if you create once, next time it will be quick.